# Module-specific constants in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, constants

I just discovered that I knew nothing about angular modules.

The value of `con` in the following directive is `baz`, which means that it does not matter where a constant is defined, i.e. it is not module dependant.

Is there a way to have module-specific constants?

```
angular.module('amodule', [])
    .constant("foo", "bar")
    .directive('helloWorld', function (foo) {
        return {
            link: function(scope) { scope.con = foo },
            restrict: 'E',
            scope:{
                name:'bind'
            },
            template: '<span>{{con}}</span>'

        }
    })

angular.module('stuff', [])
    .constant("foo", "baz")

angular.module('HelloApp', ['amodule', 'stuff'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, when you define an AngularJS artifact on a module is available for all modules if you reference them in your app module. If two modules define the same constant the last dependency defined wins and overrides the first one. The order is key in this context.
 In your case the value of con is baz because the last module referenced is stuff.